# Angular2 example in ChromeApp using ChromeDevEngine missing require?

Tags: angular, google-chrome-app

I am trying to get the angular2 demo code to run in Chrome Dev Engine.  I followed the example exactly and get the following error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
main.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined
```

However, when I put the exact same code anywhere else (static HTML served by Python) it works as expected.  I am not getting any other errors on the page when I do inspect element or inspect background page.

I also tried right clicking on the project and doing the "refactor for CSP" and that did not change the error.

```js
function AppComponent() {}

AppComponent.annotations = [
  new angular.Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
  }),
  new angular.View({
    template: '<h1>My first Angular 2 App</h1>'
  })
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  angular.bootstrap(AppComponent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.19/angular2.sfx.dev.js"></script>
<my-app></my-app>
```

Here is my Manifest

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "myApp",
  "short_name": "myApp",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "38",
  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icon_16.png",
    "128": "assets/icon_128.png"
  },
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

So I found the issue is the difference between the angular2_sfx.js and the angular2.dev.sfx.js file included by the snippet.  Below is the angular2_sfx.js. Compare that with the 30k+ lines of the dev version.

```
"use strict";
var $__angular2__;
var angular = ($__angular2__ = require("./angular2"), $__angular2__ && $__angular2__.__esModule && $__angular2__ || {default: $__angular2__});
var _prevAngular = window.angular;
angular.noConflict = function() {
  window.angular = _prevAngular;
  return angular;
};
window.angular = angular;
//# sourceMappingURL=angular2_sfx.es6.map

//# sourceMappingURL=./angular2_sfx.map
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@user41341 was on the right path but might have missed a few pieces of information. Since you installed angular2 from NPM, your repo has the angular2-sfx.js you posted which is about 12 lines of code. For some reason, the NPM repo is missing `angular2.dev.sfx.js` which has approximately 30,000 lines of code. Not quite sure why there's so much missing, but switching to the dev version should give you everything you need.

Answer (score -1):

Use `.dev.sfx.js` instead.

The `sfx.js` extension doesn't exist in the angular build you are referencing.

The main thing I can tell you to check for your angular2 test app problems is that you are pointing to all of the correct directories in your runtime assertions.